# How can I obtain the order of a combination?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given an alphabet of *n* elements, I compute the combinations on *k* elements.
For example for *n = 9* and *k = 3*, I obtain the sequences:

```
1.(1,2,3)    2.(1,2,4)    3.(1,2,5)     4.(1,2,6)     5.(1,2,7)     6.(1,2,8)   7.(1,2,9) 

8.(1,3,4)    9.(1,3,5)    10.(1,3,6)    11.(1,3,7)    12.(1,3,8)    13.(1,3,9)  14.(1,4,5)

15.(1,4,6)   16.(1,4,7)   17.(1,4,8)    18.(1,4,9)    19.(1,5,6)    ..........  N.(7,8,9)
```

where $N = \left(\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\right) = \left(\frac{9!}{6!3!}\right)$ represents the last sequence.

My question is: given a sequence, how can I obtain the position of such sequence? For example: what is the order of the sequence (4,6,8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\binom 82 = 28$ of the sequences above start with a $1$ (after the one is choosen, we are left with $2$ elements to choose from 8. $\binom 72 = 21$ start with a $2$ (no 1, after the 2 is choosen, we have to choose 2 other elements from the remaining 6). That is $(4,6,8)$ follows behind 
$$ \binom 82 + \binom 72 + \binom 62 = 28 + 21 + 15 = 64 $$
sequences which start with a 1, 2, or 3. Under thoose sequences, which start with a 4, $4$ contain a 5, namely $(4,5,x)$ for $x \in \{6,\ldots, 9\}$. Under the sequences which start with $(4,6,.)$ yours is the second, hence altogether number 
$$ 64 + 4 + 2 = 70. $$
In general, the number of $(a_1, \ldots, a_k)$ (where $a_1 < \ldots < a_k$)  under the $\binom nk$ sequences is 
$$ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=a_{i-1}+1}^{a_i-1} \binom{n-j}{k-i} $$

Comment: Great answer. But: in your opinion, can be there another formula? For example a more compact formula with a smaller number of factorials.

Comment: Hm ... you should take a look at some formulae involving binomial sums ... there are some ... but I do not remember any helpful here ...

Comment: Maybe in the second sum j starts from 0, right?

Comment: No, but there was a "+1" missing, added.

Comment: Formula doesn't return the right result..

Comment: Right ... I was not thinking well when writing the general thing ... that's not what I've done in the special case ... corrected

Comment: There was still an error, now I have corrected it. Now the formula is right. Thanks!