# Simplified:Sum of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Is it possible to come up with a formula as follows :

$\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r-1}= \binom{n+1}{r}$

for the expression:

$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=a_{i-1}+1}^{a_i - 1} \binom{n-j}{k-i}$ from [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487372/how-can-i-obtain-the-order-of-a-combination).

Comment: what means $n$ in these formulas? You need the range/values of the variables to know if is possible some simplification and how.

Comment: $n$ is a value that ranges from 5 to 64. And $r$ from $2 to 32$

Comment: There is no $r$ in your formula.